# How to auto close a MySQL connection in python when an error occurred during query execution?

Tags: mysql, transactions, python-3.7

I am working on Python-3.7 and Django 1.11. I am using mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1 Python package for MySQL connection.

I want to auto close my MySQL connection whenever any error occurs or value error is raised even then connection should be auto closed.

```py
conn = Database.connect_dbs()     
with conn.cursor() as cursor:

    qry = "Select FirstName from User where username = %s and isDeleted = 0;"
    cursor.execute(qry, [username])
    userDetail = cursor.fetchone()

    if userDetail is None:
        result.set_display_message_code('122')
        result.set_status_code(200)
        raise ValueError(
                       json.dumps(result.toJson(), cls=ComplexEncoder)
                      )

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

As I have shared a code that is raising a value error before closing the cursor and connection. I want to make sure that connection and cursor should be auto closed when value error is raised.

Some answers i have seen says "With" will auto close the cursor  but some denies it.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just wrap it in a `try: finally:` block?

[Defining Clean-up Actions (try-finally)](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions)

This is what finally blocks are for.